# Is it OK to use blue board in a basement area and a bathroom?

Tags: bathroom, drywall, basement

A contractor we’re about to hire is saying they would use the blue board for the walls in the basement area and also in the bathroom. The bathroom is going to have a standup shower unit installed made of fiberglass.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly. Blue board (gypsum board, more generally; other brands are other colors but the term is used generically) is more water resistant than plasterboard, and is a good choice anywhere that night be exposed to moisture; it's pretty standard in bathrooms.  Its main disadvantages are that it's somewhat more expensive than plasterboard, and I think a bit heavier.

The insulated end of my basement is surfaced with gypsum board, ending about 2" above the floor with pressure treated 1x4s used as baseboard to close the remaining gap. That gives me some confidence that normal levels of leakage or spill will never bother the wallboard... and if it does, these materials can tolerate abuse better than the usual ones.